# what will be the maximum value of the given formula

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

$G$ is the product of $n$ graphs $G_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$. In particular its tensor product. $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ are two vertices of $G$. Distance between x and y is:

$d_G(x, y)$ = min {n $\in$  N | each factor $G_i$ has a walk of length n from $p_i(x)$ to $p_i(y)$, where $p_i(x)$ is  projection defined as :

Let * represent either cartesian, the direct or strong product of graphs, and consider a product $G_1 * G_2* ....*G_k$. For any index *i* 1$\leq$*i*$\leq$*k*, a *Projection* map is defined as :

$p_i$ : $G_1 * G_2* ....*G_k$ $\rightarrow$ $G_i$ where $p_i$($x_1,x_2,...,x_k$)=$x_i$.

To find the eccentricity of $x$ we have to find the maximum of $d(x,y)$, where $y \in V(G)$. I am not able to find the maximum value or we may say eccentricity of a vertex.. Can anybody help me in this case. Any help or hint will be useful. Heartily thanks.

**NOTE** : I know that to find the walk of every length in the graph, the graph must not be a bipartite graph.

Comment: Your title is only weakly representative of the problem you ask about.  A better title might be "Eccentricity of vertices in product graphs".  Also it would be good to state that the penultimate paragraph gives the *definition* of eccentricity of vertex $x$.  The final sentence ("NOTE") is unclear.  What is "the walk of every length in the graph" and how is this related to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is a nontrivial problem. It is completely handled in the paper [Centers of $n$-fold products of graphs](https://doi.org/10.7151/dmgt.1247) by Sarah Bendall and Richard Hammack. (An alternate link to a PDF can be found on Hammack's website: [https://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/reprints/DMGT04.pdf](https://www.people.vcu.edu/%7Erhammack/reprints/DMGT04.pdf))

Comment: @AndrewUzzell If fixing a dead link, it's better to do it in such a way that the problem doesn't reoccur: including the authors and title of the paper, and when possible a DOI link.